# how to create a drop down in android which does not hide the background?

Tags: java, android

i wanted to create a drop down which doesnot hide the background and which drops the other labels below the drop down list elements..how can i do it?

Once i click the spinner the items should be displayed below the spinner on the same page...and the other spinners below the first spinner should move down below the items of the first spinner...please help..!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  Spinner spnr;
  String[] celebrities = {
      "Chris Hemsworth",
      "Jennifer Lawrence",
      "Jessica Alba",
      "Brad Pitt",
      "Tom Cruise",
      "Johnny Depp",
      "Megan Fox",
      "Paul Walker",
      "Vin Diesel"
  };
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    spnr = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, celebrities);
    spnr.setAdapter(adapter);
    spnr.setOnItemSelectedListener(
              new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                          int arg2, long arg3) {
                    int position = spnr.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You have selected "+celebrities[+position],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  }
                  @Override
                  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  }
              }
          );
```

Comment: Post your XML file code and if possible then please put Screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that this way if you want. Initialize your array of celebrities in values/array.xml file under `<resources>` tag.

```
<resources>
   <string-array name="spinnerItemsCelebrities">
      <item>Choose celebrity</item>
      <item>Vin Diesel</item>
      <item>Megan Fox</item>
      <item>Brad Pitt</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Then, in file where your spinner is you add android:entries line.

```
<Spinner
   android:id="@+id/sppiner1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:entries="@array/spinnerItemsCelebrities" />
```

After that you have your sppiner combo box drop down which does not hide your background. You can use `Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()` method to get string you selected on your `spinner1`.

Comment: got the solution..i used expandable list views...thanks anyway...!